# SQL Server High availability User Login

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server high availability. When we add a user on the primary instance in high availability the user is added on the secondary on a database level not on the actual instance level.

Do we have to do this manually when the primary instance fails over and then connected to the secondary?

Is there a way for it to sync over automatically on the secondary at instance level to and not just database level?

Comment: You mean you can't find the server login that corresponds to the database login?

Comment: Exactly on my high availability I've set up a login for my member of staff he is on the database level and Instance level on the primary. But for the Secondary on high Availably he has only been copied over on database level not on the Instance level for some reason.